# chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest not getting triggered when chrome.exe is launched with --disable-extensions-file-access-check flag

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

In my extension, I wanna do some logging with all file:/// protocol urls & don't want to let user deselect "Allow file urls" check box for extension.

So, I launched chrome with flag : --disable-extensions-file-access-check

But when chrome is launched, i am seeing onBeforeRequest event is not at all getting triggered for file:/// urls.

I have mentioned file:/// in manifest file as well.

Comment: Did you receive any kind of error?

Comment: No. onBeforeRequest Listener is not at all called.